# Weird slowdown on data returned by compiled function (bug?)

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, intersection

Mathematica 13.1 - I was cleaning up some computations and I got a x3 time increase when I reduced things to loop over.
Full context is a bit convoluted, I stripped the most I could but the problem seems to be tied with the actual lists used, so I have to dump them as they are

```
list1 = {{{1,2},{1,4},{1,8},{1,13},{1,21},{2,4},{2,8},{2,13},{2,21},{4,8},{4,13},{4,21},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{2,13},{2,21},{4,8},{4,13},{4,21},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{2,13},{2,21},{4,8},{4,13},{4,21},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{1,8},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{2,13},{2,21},{4,13},{4,21},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{1,8},{1,13},{2,4},{2,8},{2,13},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{2,21},{4,21},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{4,8},{4,13},{4,21},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{1,8},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{4,13},{4,21},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{4,13},{4,21},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{4,13},{4,21},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{2,13},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{4,21},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{4,13},{4,21},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{2,13},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{4,21},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{1,8},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{2,13},{4,13},{8,13},{4,21},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{2,13},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{2,13},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{2,13},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{4,8},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{8,13},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{1,8},{1,13},{2,4},{2,8},{2,13},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{2,13},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{2,13},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13}},{{1,2},{1,4},{1,8},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{2,13},{4,13},{8,13}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{8,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{8,13}},{{1,2},{1,4},{1,8},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{1,8},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{8,13},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{8,13},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{8,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{8,13}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4}},{{1,2},{2,4}},{{1,2},{4,8},{13,21}},{{1,2},{4,8}},{{1,2}}};
list2 = {{{1,1}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,4}},{{1,2},{2,2},{2,8},{8,8}},{{1,2},{2,2},{2,13},{13,13}},{{1,2},{2,2},{2,21}},{{1,1},{1,4},{4,8},{8,8}},{{1,1},{1,4},{4,4},{4,13},{13,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{8,8}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,4},{4,13},{13,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,4},{4,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{13,13}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{8,8},{4,21},{8,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{4,4},{2,13},{4,13},{4,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{8,13},{13,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{8,8},{8,21}},{{1,2},{2,2},{2,8},{8,13},{13,13}},{{1,2},{2,2},{2,8},{8,8},{8,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,13},{4,4},{4,13},{13,21}},{{1,1},{1,4},{4,8},{8,13},{13,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{8,13},{13,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{8,8},{8,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{8,21},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,4},{4,13},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{8,13},{13,21}},{{1,1}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,4}},{{1,2},{2,2},{2,8},{8,8}},{{1,2},{2,2},{2,13}},{{1,1},{1,4},{4,8},{8,8}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{8,8}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,4},{4,13}},{{1,2},{1,4},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{4,13},{8,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{2,8},{4,8},{8,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{8,13}},{{1,1},{13,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,4},{13,13}},{{1,2},{2,2},{2,8},{13,13}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8},{13,13}},{{1,1}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,4}},{{1,2},{2,2},{2,8}},{{1,2},{2,4},{4,8}},{{1,1},{8,8}},{{1,1},{8,13},{13,21}},{{1,2},{2,4},{8,13},{13,21}},{{1,1},{8,8}},{{1,2},{2,4},{8,8}},{{1,1}},{{1,2},{2,4}},{{1,1},{4,4},{13,13}},{{1,1},{4,4}},{{1,1}}};

(* reference uncompiled function *)
sum[x_]:=Table[i[[1]]+i[[2]],{i,x}]

cSum=Compile[{{x,_Integer,2}},Table[Compile`GetElement[x,k,1]+Compile`GetElement[x,k,2],{k,1,Length[x]}]];

(* anomalous function *)
f[list_]:=Intersection[list[[1]],#]&/@ConstantArray[0,{700,6}]

tester[function_,list_]:=Module[{temp=function/@list},First@RepeatedTiming@f[temp]]
```

From my point of view `f` is the function doing some brute force counting, `cSum` is an helper compiled function, `list1` is the data used, `list2` is the "optimized" data. Simply `list1` and `list2` have the same number of rows, but for each row `list2` has less elements than `list1`. So here's the problem: how could `f`, that is `Intersection`, spend more time working with a smaller list?

```
tester[cSum, list1]
tester[cSum, list2]
tester[sum, list1]
tester[sum, list2]
(* 0.00129825 *)
(* 0.00386076 *)    (* !!! *)
(* 0.00141084 *)
(* 0.00143332 *)
```

The next test is to show that actual data stored in lists matters, maybe it's something related to compression.

```
tester[cSum, 0 list1]
tester[cSum, 0 list2]
tester[sum, 0 list1]
tester[sum, 0 list2]
(* 0.00608312 *)
(* 0.00495957 *)
(* 0.00157673 *)
(* 0.00148108 *)
```

And while the following behaves as expected too...

```
rlist1 = Map[RandomInteger[100] &, list1, {-1}];
rlist2 = Map[RandomInteger[100] &, list2, {-1}];
tester[cSum, rlist1]
tester[cSum, rlist2]
tester[sum, rlist1]
tester[sum, rlist2]
(* 0.00123285 *)
(* 0.00124893 *)
(* 0.00149976 *)
(* 0.00128301 *)
```

...this does not! *consistently*

```
rlist1 = Map[RandomInteger@100 &, list1, {-1}];
rlist2 = RandomSample[#, Max[1, Length@# - 10]] & /@ rlist1;
tester[cSum, rlist1]
tester[cSum, rlist2]
tester[sum, rlist1]
tester[sum, rlist2]
(* 0.00119549 *)
(* 0.00368292 *)    (* !!! *)
(* 0.00144059 *)
(* 0.00133897 *)
```

Indeed the actual relation between my `list1` and `list2` is not just that each row is smaller in `list2`, but each row in `list2` is a (almost) a subset of each row in `list1`.
I've reproduced this on [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##zVhba9swFH7Prwis7KWCRqrYzErAo2xjsI2xlb0YkbmpkorFTrBlyDD@7Zks2/FNtiXHlL1YsY70nXO@czPxXP5MPZeztXvasZDD@XIexzEEKAHiieXTkk94KxcExYKkBEkJyiQok2C5h7M9nO1Z2ZuVvcHbdBU/ci1TYsEca2pEmGOVuFiJPg4XFigts2v2Wg1luZZBIqZ22jy4lyXFJCmlYlKfwrGGdObjWHMGEtEEsA0yCamGbE7I32V2D1eQfqYb18TIYhhHuYFOHaKGFGgQNVVzNAz6qDy7oCI12rPSDV1HzTw0Q@0xzIiW4ezRTeO@vDJpnt22DNmg0q2@o1@ovUWj0aqUcerMhfrB8k3NYtW/JLmbzdIvRlR8MapiUdeAzuxZDfZQWTBCacMDVHz0ZJvw7AFuYFUluMztNqLqct3swcu4mK@m/bYJ2D0YrcYI72ofuNVtsOHEVzvZtsZq4lUj2hu9Hoya@XXme2KuEVmt4Hca9D8P206eNObrJGU6VImGZfbSYwoOFHZfFvclVFWmz3P3GIGt9mY6HmAH@VVU1RCASi5gzQuYDYEw8pzjirxbPriPO@owx4GEXIsFEQJiBo4Jma1/Rt7yfu8dmDgRx0ew@uxzuqVBOklAdjEX//5E@Ycd9ajPnSP4AyC57pAgAS/k4Av1t/zZOZKEkLvZxkmnUmpPqiII6ZqzvS83pWXgFXl9Y9/v/ZC7Pn8fBO5fZwHit4sFeCMs5TQUt5xN5Mt7K1CgfQ@Yz@2v@6codYFT77AsDt3Y6aEEfGRByO0f9EBdTp8emMf8rb1x0rOEnDKAq1/CJnHnW@Q90qBQl/ID5vIPGNLeQ@e9sH0sLE@dTv8A) (Mathematica version 12)

My first hypothesis was that if a list is found to be a subset of another list maybe some compression algorithm kicks in, but this is easily disprove clearing all variables and declaring just `list2`, it would still be "too slow"... It feels so obscure, like this would affect only certain type of data!? Based on what?